# AWS Amplify setup graphQL for retrieving child objects from dynamoDB

Tags: react-native, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am using the AWS amplify project with react native, following their docs. I ran into an issue when I try and retrieve data. I cannot for the life of me work out how the return the child related objects along with it. I want all datasheets and all points related to the datasheets.

I set the depth value to 10, as the default was 2.  Any ideas would be great!

Here is my GraphQL schema:

```
type Point @model {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  points: Int!
  models: String!
}
type Datasheet @model {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  name: String!
  points: [Point] @hasMany
}
```

here is some example data

```
point:
{
 "id": "63",
 "createdAt": "2023-06-19T21:23:40.548Z",
 "datasheet": "51",
 "models": "1 model",
 "points": "800",
 "updatedAt": "2023-06-19T21:23:40.548Z"
}
datasheet:
{
 "id": "51",
 "createdAt": "2023-06-20T08:21:32.281Z",
 "name": "Stompa",
 "points": [
  "63"
 ],
 "units": [
  "51"
 ],
 "updatedAt": "2023-06-20T08:21:32.281Z"
}
```

code to fetch datasheets:

```
      console.log('GET datasheets');
      const sheetData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listDatasheets));
      const sheets = sheetData.data.listDatasheets.items;
      console.log(sheets[0].points.items);

      console.log(sheets);
      setSheets(sheets);
```

I tried a belongsTo on the points schema and that didn't work, and I figure I dont need to look up the relationship that way so I removed it again.

I am expecting a return of
datasheets:[{
name: "Stompa",
points: [{
models: "1 model"
points: 800
}]
}]

whats currently happening is i get the datasheet, but no points values.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is with the data model.
It is expected to have a field for the key like 'oneManyId'

for example for the above, `datasheetPointsId` Added that and it's golden.